How can I download pdf manually from ngx-extended-pdf-viewer in angular 13
I have installed  ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@18 and angular 13. It works well. But now I want to download edit pdf file with separate button, how can i achieve that. please help
in HTML file
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer #pdfViewer [src]="pdfSrc" [contextMenuAllowed]="false"
                         [enablePrint]="false"
                         [showSidebarButton]="false"
                         [showOpenFileButton]="false"
                         [showSecondaryToolbarButton]="false"
                         height="80vh"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>

<button (click)="downloadPdf()">Download it</button>

in ts file
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import SignaturePad from 'signature_pad';
import {PDFDocumentProxy} from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
import {PDFDocument} from 'pdf-lib';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {IPDFViewerApplication, NgxExtendedPdfViewerComponent, PdfDownloadedEvent} from "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // pdf document
  pdfSrc = '../assets/download.pdf';
  pdfDoc?: PDFDocumentProxy;
  pdfDownloaded: any;
  @ViewChild('pdfViewer') pdfViewer!: NgxExtendedPdfViewerComponent;
  
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private ngZone: NgZone) {
  }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('dfsd');
  }


  downloadPdf() {
    // Get the PDF data from the PDF viewer
    // @ts-ignore
    const editedPdfData = this.pdfViewer?.getCurrentDocumentAsBlob();

    // Create a Blob URL for the edited PDF data
    const blob = new Blob([editedPdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Create a download link
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'edited-file.pdf'; // Specify the desired filename

    // Append the link to the document, trigger the download, and then remove the link
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

    // Revoke the Blob URL to free up memory
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
}


not only this i have done so many tries to solve it but i don't get it's solution.

This solution is only possible for versions equal to or greater than version 7
Add import
 import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerService } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
change your code here:
   constructor( private http: HttpClient, private ngZone: NgZone, private ngxService: NgxExtendedPdfViewerService) { }
and here:
   const editedPdfData = this.ngxService?.getCurrentDocumentAsBlob();

Can you pls use proper code format and syntax?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for your support. I have already fixed this in same way that you have mention.

This function is available from version 7 onwards. In previous versions it is only possible to download the file from the toolbar, download file.If you need it to be compatible with ie11. the only version that works 100% is using the "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer" version: "5.3",
